# What are real world applications of the Duistermaat–Heckman formula?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, mathematics, semiclassical, applied-physics

In the famous 1984 paper "The Moment Map and Equivariant Cohomology" by Atiyah and Bott, an equivariant de Rham theory was presented in relation to the [Duistermaat–Heckman formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duistermaat%E2%80%93Heckman_formula)
$$ \int_M e^{-itf} \frac{\omega^n}{n!} = \sum_p \frac{e^{-itf(p)}}{(it)^n \text{e}(p)},$$
where $(M,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold and $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is the moment map on $M$ coming from a circle action.

This sparked my curiosity in the physical applications of equivariant cohomology (i.e., equivariant de Rham theory), especially the above formula.

**What are real world applications of the Duistermaat–Heckman formula?**

By real world applications, I mean physical applications in classical mechanics, statistical mechanics, quantum mechanics, or quantum field theory, but probably not string theory. I would appreciate if someone could provide real world applications of the Duistermaat–Heckman formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some applications that might qualify for your criterion of 'real world':

Yasui, Y., & Ogura, W. (1996). [Vortex filament in a three-manifold and the Duistermaat-Heckman formula](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9508118). Physics Letters A, 210(4-5), 258-266.

Karki, T., & Niemi, A. J. (1994). [On the Duistermaat-Heckman Integration Formula and Integrable Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9402041). arXiv preprint hep-th/9402041.

Bismut, J. M. (2011). [Duistermaat–Heckman formulas and index theory](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/%7Ebismut/Bismut/2011e.pdf). In Geometric Aspects of Analysis and Mechanics (pp. 1-55). Birkhäuser Boston.

Zhang, L., Jiang, Y., & Wu, J. (2019). [Duistermaat–Heckman measure and the mixture of quantum states](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02630). Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical, 52(49), 495203.